# Python Pandas - Check if a value is in the top n rows

Tags: python, pandas

We have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
table = {"Col 1":{"0":"Row 1","1":"Row 2","2":"Row 3","3":"Row 4","4":"Row 5","5":"Row 6","6":"Row 7","7":"Row 8","8":"Row 9","9":"Row 10"},"Col 2":{"0":0,"1":1,"2":0,"3":0,"4":1,"5":0,"6":0,"7":1,"8":1,"9":1}}
tabledf = pd.DataFrame(table)
tabledf["Col 3"] = "??"
```

Which returns this:

```
    Col 1  Col 2 Col 3
0   Row 1      0    ??
1   Row 2      1    ??
2   Row 3      0    ??
3   Row 4      0    ??
4   Row 5      1    ??
5   Row 6      0    ??
6   Row 7      0    ??
7   Row 8      1    ??
8   Row 9      1    ??
9  Row 10      1    ??
```

In column 3, we want to show 1 in the top/first 2 rows that have 1 in col 2 (and 0 in the following).
This is the desired output:

```
Col 3
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
```

How do we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic can be split into 2 criteria, which must both be met:

1. `Col 2` equal to 1.
2. Count of `Col 2` equal to 1 is less than or equal to 2.

You can then apply this in a vectorised fashion, converting to `int` as a final step:

```
df['Col 3'] = (df['Col 2'].eq(1) & df['Col 2'].eq(1).cumsum().le(3)).astype(int)

print(df)

    Col 1  Col 2  Col 3
0   Row 1      0      0
1   Row 2      1      1
2   Row 3      0      0
3   Row 4      0      0
4   Row 5      1      1
5   Row 6      0      0
6   Row 7      0      0
7   Row 8      1      0
8   Row 9      1      0
9  Row 10      1      0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tabledf['Col 3'] = 0

tabledf.loc[tabledf['Col 2'].loc[lambda x: x==1][:2].index, 'Col 3']=1

print(tabledf)
    Col 1  Col 2  Col 3
0   Row 1      0      0
1   Row 2      1      1
2   Row 3      0      0
3   Row 4      0      0
4   Row 5      1      1
5   Row 6      0      0
6   Row 7      0      0
7   Row 8      1      0
8   Row 9      1      0
9  Row 10      1      0
```

Comment: Thanks! Not defining it in the columns row?